# Js optinal options during call function

Tags: javascript

```
bot.commands.others.ping({
  lang: "tr",
  client: client,
  type: msg,
});
```

```
async function cmd({ lang, client, type, content, embed }) {
  if (!embed) embed = false;
  embed = {};
  if (embed) type.reply("yes");
  if (!content) content = `Pong! ${client.ws.ping}ms !`;
  type.reply(`${content}`);
}

module.exports = cmd;
```

This is my code i wanna make optinal
embed choice need help!

Like if user type

```
client: 
type:
embed: ({title: 'smth'})
```

Message will be sent with embed

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.assign` or `spread operator`.

```js
const defaults = { v1: 'hello', v2: 'world' }
const input = { v1: 'hi'}

const merged = Object.assign( {}, defaults, input )
const merged = {...defaults, ...input}
```

In both cases, the default value will be overridden.

Comment: When using spread, you don't need the extra brackets around `v1:'hi'`

Comment: that is correct, but i am formatting it as if it was coming from a function argument, and trying to match the other call for comparison.

Comment: But then you have to spread that too.

Comment: yes, i just rewrote it as intended.